# SQL: How to find datetime that contains specific minutes?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a database where a new entry gets added every minute.

I want to make a query where the result is in an intervall of 1 hour (e.g. 2016-06-19 20:01, 2016-06-19 21:01, ...).

This is my current approach (I used minute 42 of every hour, because that might only occur in the minutes part of the date): `SELECT * FROM 'raw_data' WHERE CONTAINS ('date', "42")>0`.

However I get an empty result, even so my test database looks like that:
[image: My test Database]

Does anyone know why I get an empty result, is it because I am using a String to compare with datetime?

Comment: `where minute(date) = 42`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT * FROM 'raw_data' WHERE DATE_FORMAT('date', '%i') LIKE '42';
```

Or more precise you can use [MINUTE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) function:

```
SELECT * FROM 'raw_data' WHERE MINUTE('date') = 42;
```

Comment: Perfect, then I can simply use first minute of every hour and do not need to worry about seconds or dates that contain 01.

Answer (score 2):

You can use minute function

```
SELECT * FROM 'raw_data' WHERE minute(`date`) = '42';
```